# TCP Receiver Window size

Tags: networking, tcp

Is there a way to change the TCP receiver window size using any of winsock api functions? The RCVBUF value just increases the capacity of the temporary storage. I need to the improve the speed of data transfer and I thought increasing the receiver window size would help but I couldn't find a way to improve it using winsock api. Is there a way to do it or should I modify the registry?

Answer (score 0):

> The RCVBUF value just increases the capacity of the temporary storage.

No, the RCVBUF value sets the size of the receive buffer, which *is* the maximum receive window. No 'just' about it. The receive window is the amount if data the sender may send, which the receiver has to be able to store somewhere ... guess where? In the receive buffer.

On Windows it was historically 8k for decades, which was far too low, and gave rise to an entire sub-industry of 'download tweaks' which just raised the default (some of them also played dangerously with other settings, which isn't usually a good idea).